# LaTeX friendly wiki encyclopedia

Tags: wiki

I'm looking for a LaTeX friendly wiki software. I know handwiki.org (https://handwiki.org) encyclopedia is one of the friendliest web sites that runs Mediawiki and allows (1) to use BibTeX files for citations (2) Exporting Wikitext to LaTex using WZI-file export (where a LaTeX file is one of the supported formats. But I'm looking for something opposite: I want to convert my LaTeX articles and books into the wiki format so I can re-post them online as wiki. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to convert _existing_ LaTeX articles to some sort of wiki syntax, or do you want to author _new_ LaTeX documents to then convert to wiki syntax?  The two cases are different as in the second case you can avoid things that cause issues.  As part of the nLab project, I was involved in converting some existing articles to its (instiki) syntax and that was not trivial. But I also used LaTeX to author posts there directly and that was much easier.

Comment: If your wiki software handles Markdown then you could consider converting `.tex` to `.md` using Pandoc. This can be combined with MathJax for math rendering.

Comment: Mediawiki has extensions for these things: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Bibtex and https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MathJax